# Case not falling to correct number/program not reading clock correctly

Tags: java, switch-statement, case, clock

I'm working on a tutorial about switch/cases, I believe that I have copied the program to the character but it returns the incorrect month. Anyone spot my mistake? Thanks.

import java.util.*;
class ClockTalk {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //get current time and date
    Calendar now  = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    //display greeting
    if (hour < 12)
            System.out.println("Good moring.\n");
    else if (hour < 17)
            System.out.println("Good afternoon.\n");
    else
            System.out.println("Good evening.\n");

    //begin time message by showing the minutes
    System.out.print("It's");
    if (minute != 0) {
        System.out.print(" " + minute + " ");
        System.out.print( (minute != 1) ? "minutes" : "minute");
        System.out.print(" past");
    }

    //Display the hour
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print( (hour > 12) ? (hour - 12) : hour );
    System.out.print(" o'clock on ");

    //display the name of the month
    switch (month) {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("January");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.print("Febuary");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.print("March");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.print("April");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.print("May");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.print("June");
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.print("July");
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.print("August");
            break;
        case 9:
            System.out.print("September");
            break;
        case 10:
            System.out.print("October");
            break;
        case 11:
            System.out.print("November");
            break;
        case 12:
            System.out.print("December");

    }


    //display the date and year
    System.out.println(" " + day + ", " + year + ".");



}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Calendar.MONTH` starts from ZERO. That could be the reason. You need to add `case 0:`

Example:

```
  case 0:
    System.out.print("January");
    break;
```

As per Calendar [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

> The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

Comment: Or, alternatively, keep your current cases and switch on (month+1).

Comment: It would be (month+1) :) (pst: try using maths)

Comment: Correct, month from calendar comes as 0, make sense. Deleting my comment.

Comment: BOOM. that was it. thanks a bunch. I double checked the tut Im using and it didnt have case 0. it is older, so I'll assume that got changed at some point.

Comment: @willer: glad it helped. Enjoy coding.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure I will enjoy it once I stop pulling out my hair. :D